# What is the reason if Roles.AddUserToRole(..) does not work?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I implemented membership in asp.net, I have a manager that can define users, users have USER role, when I use below code to assign role, it does not work:

```
Roles.AddUserToRole(txtUsername.Text, "USER");
```

Now my question is: 
What is the reasons?

when I log in and check its roles, there is no role. I use this code for detect role:

```
string[] role = Roles.GetRolesForUser(txtUserName.Text);
```

Comment: because your code is buggy? Please, show code! how do you expect us to guess what you did wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx):

1. Role management is not *enabled*. -or- User is already assigned to the specified role.
2. roleName is an empty string or contains a comma (,). -or- username is an empty string or contains a comma (,).
3. roleName is null. -or- username is null.